# TFS scrum board alternatives

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, scrum, scrumboard

Due to some reasons I'm unable to use TFS scrum board, though I'm using TFS itself. Are there any tools/plugins which offer similar integration with TFS tasks? The only one I found is Scrum Power Tools, but it's in my opinion insufficient and not so good quality. Are there any alternatives to TFS scrum board?

Comment: Where are your work items?

Comment: Then why can't you use the TFS boards?

Comment: Because some admin can't figure it out and dev team can't overcome this.

Comment: Admins? What do admins have to do with where you do work item tracking? That's a development team and product owner things...sounds like you need to get them to give me a call 

Comment: Ha :), you know, corporation... We're just a cog in the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SEP Teamworks by sep.com. I saw it somewhere recently and it looked ok.

Comment: At first glance (demo video) seems nice Though I couldn't quickly find any information about a license. Is it free (seems it's not)?

Comment: The website says it's Free work item management. The place I saw it being used told me that it is free, so it must be free.

Answer (score 2):

If you are still looking, [Eylean Board](http://www.eylean.com/tfs) offers a two way integration with TFS. All the information is shared and updated in both systems, so you can use the scrum board in Eylean and have all the information updated in TFS.

Besides the scrum board itself, it allows to add various information and details to the tasks, track time and generates reports for your convenience.

Answer (score 1):

I am prefer [Work Item Manager and Project Dashboard](http://www.telerik.com/teampulse/tfs) from Telerik. I like for aggregation features, it is useful when you need review tasks of other developers.